# Nodejs udemy course code error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an issue with running some code from a udemy nodejs course. I get what it does (or what it's supposed to do), however I don't get why the greet2 function is showing me 'undefined' once the event is done.

The code is:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var greet = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/greet.txt', 'utf8');

console.log(greet);

var greet2 = fs.readFile(__dirname, + '/greet.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});

console.log('Done!');
```

I am being show in the console:

Hello world!
Done!
undefined

Any idea on why am I getting undefined for greet2?

Thanks

Comment: might be worth trying `console.log(err);` to see if there's any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var greet2 = fs.readFile(__dirname, + '/greet.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

To:

```
var greet2 = fs.readFile(__dirname + '/greet.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

(an extra comma)

Your code worked but what you passed to the `readFile` function was a `__dirname`, then `+'/greet.txt'` which evaluates to `NaN` and then other parameters like `'utf8'` and the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript functions always return something. If you don't specify something to return in the function, 'undefined' is returned by default.

But don't worry, this doesn't affect anything, you can ignore it.
It's not going to cause any harm.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea on why am I getting undefined for greet2?

`fs.readFile` is an asynchronous function and it has no return when it's 'initialized' soo when you call it it will not return any value.

One example where you have an initial value and an asynchronous call is `var timeout = setTimeout(callback, mm)`. `tout` will hold a value that you can use to clear it `clearTimeout(tout)`.